# Can ProxySQL auto failover in a Galera cluster?

Tags: database, percona, galera, proxysql, percona-xtradb-cluster

We have a 3 node Galera Cluster with proxysql in front. I have seen where you can have all 3 Galera nodes in the same hostgroup and proxysql will round robin to all 3 nodes which gives you HA and basically an automatic failover if a database node goes down.

Is there a way to have it auto failover if you don't want to round robin and only want connections on 1 node and failover if that node goes down?

- Route all traffic to node 1
- If node 1 fails route all traffic to node 2
- If node 1 and 2 fail route to node 3

this setup would be similar to using backups in haproxy but just not seeing if this is possible in ProxySQL

round robin works, but due to the amount of traffic writing to all 3 nodes causes issues with wsrep replication.